# WinApi аттачинг к службам windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, pywin32

Мне требуется аттачится к сервису и перехватывать функции winapi.
[Пример](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/727-win-guide-to-hooking-windows-apis-with-python) с процессами, который я смог реализовать с помощью pywin32 и Deavire
По аналогии пытаюсь хукать службы

```
    for service in psutil.win_service_iter():
    try:
        hook = spyManager.CreateHook('winsvc.h!ControlService', 1 | 2 | 4)
        print(hook)
        hook.Attach(service.name(), True)
        print(3)
        hook.Hook(True)
        print(hook)
        print(f'Done {service.name()}')
    except Exception:
        print(f'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFfff {service.name()}')
```

все попытки попадают в эксепшен, если пытаться без него, то ошибка следующая

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:main.py", line 29, in <module>
hook.Attach(service.name(), True)
File "C:\\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\6E5EC37D-CF01-49B1-96C7-5E8ECF21A14Cx0x2x0.py", line 
1400, in Attach
, sync)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, 'DeviareCOM', '-2147024809', None, 0, 
-2147024809), None)
```

К сожалению все [ссылки](https://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/support/index.html) на документацию не рабочие

Comment: а вы выполнили условия ? 1 Make the application load a python.dll file so it can run the Python code.
2 Make the application call the Py_Initialize function to initialize the Python interpreter.

Comment: можно ссылку на источник?

Comment: так по вашей ссылке в начале примеров

Comment: Я для этого использую библиотеку Deviare, и там про процессы, с которыми у меня все работает. Вопрос, могу ли я прицепиться к сервисам

Comment: Я использую не WinAppDbg, а Deviare, и код из примера с iExplorer работал.